# Is expiry policy is still applicable for read data from checkpoint/persistes store?

Tags: java, ignite

I have used Ignite Persistence functionality to stored data if ignite serve failed or stopped.

However while restarting the server previous data is loaded in cache but its applied expiry policy is not set.

My question is: How can I check meta-info of stored data in Ignite cache?

Comment: How do you check, that expiry policy is not set? You can get configured expiry policy from a cache by using a code like this: `cache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.class).getExpiryPolicyFactory().create()`

Comment: I have checked using gridgain console and dada size of the cache. I wait till that entry is remove but it didn't

Answer (score 1):

Entries, that are stored in persistence, but haven't been accessed since startup, are not eagerly expired. So, if you get cache size, the result will actually include values, that should be expired, but haven't been accessed yet.

But if you try to read these values, you will get `null`, and `cache.size()` will give you smaller value next time.

So, entries are actually expired, but it doesn't happen eagerly.

If you want expired entries to be expired after restart, you can access all entries, for example, using [ScanQuery](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.3/docs/cache-queries#section-scan-queries).

Comment: I have access all entries but still data is not expired